# Top Property not Working with %, but Works with px

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I'm trying to position by percent in order for it to stay in place (it kind of floats around not centered on an empty part of the page), while still making it accessible and look good across different screen sizes and not really off to one side.

The problem is that, while I can use left: x% to adjust it accordingly, trying to use top does not do anything unless I'm specifying pixels, not percent. If I try to alter bottom in *any* way, it latches the div I'm trying to position to up near my header, and altering bottom with px makes it go up the screen from the header area.

Absolutely positioning the content_wrapper actually makes the top attribute work just fine, but it pushes a bunch of space below my footer and adds a scrollbar, pretty much ruining the design beyond the footer.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="content_wrapper">

    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="marquee">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer_wrapper">
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    /* background: image.jpg; */
    background-size: cover;
}

.marquee {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    width: 30em;
    left: 15%;
}

#footer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -43px 0px;

}

#content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -41px 0px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 4em;
    margin-top: -4.07em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #2A64A7;
    border-top: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

(There is a float or two in there, like in #content, not necessary to the layout, but which are attempts to fix the issue.)

Any help in this matter would be hugely appreciated. Sorry about all the code, but I feel like the footer bits are necessary simply because of the aforementioned issue with scrolling.

Comment: wich is the div you talk about ? #container as height:100% ; but 100% of what value ? i see no height given to body (and html actually)

Comment: .marquee is the div I am referring to. Should I just make container a set height and then specify another height with the media tag for smaller screens, etc?

Comment: i guess if you set height:100% to html and body, it should fixed it. html will take 100% of window, body 100% of html , #container 100% of body and .marquee will have a valid value to calculate % from top within #container

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have height for html and body set to 100%. Forgot to include it in my example above. Still nothing

Comment: I found a solution, sort of... If I have #container with: { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; } It works when I use the top property and %. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly with the bottom attribute, so this is more of a hotfix and less of an elegant solution. But it works well when I resize the browser, which is what I was going for all along. Anyone else got something that might work better perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the

```
height: auto !important;
```

in #container.

That lets you use % for top or bottom.